# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class. (export declare class AngularFirestore {)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm facing the issue with the Angular & Firebase setup.

**Time: 555ms

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/fire/firebase.app.module' in 'C:\Users\pavi9003\Desktop\AI&ML\qatarAI\aidemo\src\app'

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:85:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

85 export declare class AngularFirestore {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


ERROR in node_modules/@angular/fire/firestore/firestore.d.ts:85:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

85 export declare class AngularFirestore {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**
```

[Angular CLI and Ivy Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG8e6.png)

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: Yes. @Mr.ZeroOne